# How to split up a string in an array based on a specific marker

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, replace, format

I have the dataset below with some code to identify a marker within a string to split and format properly. What am I doing wrong? I cannot seem to see my place of error.

Desired outcome:

Examples:

```
 Dividing!polynomials --> Dividing Polynomials
 Categorical!data!and!probabilities ---> Categorical Data and Probabilities
```

**"and" and "of" should always be lowercased**

Reproducible example:

```
skilllist = ['Dividing!polynomials', 'Categorical!data!and!probabilities', 'Systems!of!linear!equations', 'Scatterplots!and!graphs']


for word in tempskilllist:
    s = list(word)
    
    for letter, index in enumerate(s):
        if letter == '!':
            counter = index + 1
            negcounter = index - 1
            if s[counter] == 'a':
                s[index].replace('!',' ')
            
            else:
                s[counter].upper()
                s[index].replace('!',' ')




print(tempskilllist)
```

### Update

I forgot to include the 'of' feature I would like help for that too.

P.S. I needed to include some kind of marker because it was necessary for integration with other code.

### Edit

This is a very micro problem with my code. In another part of my dataset, the "A" in "and" is capitalized and I am not sure how to make it a lowercase "a".

Dataset:

```
topiclist = ['Advanced Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Basic Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis']
```

**"And" should become "and"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the counter and negcounter you have in your code are for. I eliminated them because they are not necessary to get your desired outcome.

There are a few different ways to get the result you are looking for. This is an example that I have tested and will work. See my inline comments for details.

```
skillList = ['Dividing!polynomials', 'Categorical!data!and!probabilities', 'Systems!of!linear!equations', 'Scatterplots!and!graphs']

skillsToSentence = []

for word in skillList:
    sentence = word.replace("!", " ") # Replacing ! with spaces
    sentenceList = sentence.split() # Split will create list of words separating on spaces by default
    words = [] # List of words to store capitalized words
    for word in sentenceList:
        if word.lower() != "and" and word.lower() != "of": # Checking to see if the word needs to be title case, casting word to lower case
            word = word.title() # This Will Make The Word Title Case
            words.append(word)
        else: # If 'and' or 'or' is captialized in skillList, this will make sure it is always lower case
            word = word.lower() # this will make the word lower case
            words.append(word)
    joinedWords = " ".join(words) # Joining our list of words with a space between each element
    skillsToSentence.append(joinedWords) # Appending the string created in the line above to a final list

print(skillsToSentence)
```

Comment: See my edit, casting the word to lower case using .lower() will fix your issue. The behavior was occurring because my if statement was only checking for 'and'. 'And' or 'AND' would not be caught using the if statement before my edit.

Answer (score 0):

There were few problems with your code.
First, you did not used 'enumerate' properly, as enumerate unpacks and gives index of the element and element. So there you have to make correction.
Second, the statements that you are writing like , replace or upper, are not affecting the list. You need to explicitly assign these changes to the respective index of the list, for example, s[index] = s[index].replace('!', 'a')

Given below is your code with modifications.
PS: I have used 'join' in my code, you can read about them :)

```
tempskilllist = ['Dividing!polynomials', 'Categorical!data!and!probabilities', 'Systems!of!linear!equations',
             'Scatterplots!and!graphs']
new_tempskilllist = []

for word in tempskilllist:
    s = list(word)

    for index, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter == '!':
            counter = index + 1
            negcounter = index - 1
            if s[index] == 'a':
                s[index] = s[index].replace('!', ' ')

            else:
                s[index] = s[index].upper()
                s[index] = s[index].replace('!', ' ')
    new_tempskilllist.append(''.join(s))

print(new_tempskilllist)
```

Comment: thank you so much brother! I made an edit to my original question as another problem arose. Do you mind helping me?